# Как реализовать катание шарика по сфере в терминах матриц?

Tags: javascript, матрицы, геометрия, webgl

#### Цель

Необходимо создать две сферы, одну из которых можно катать по поверхности другой при помощи мышки и реализовать камеру, которую можно перемещать вокруг этих шаров при помощи клавиатуры.

#### Реализация

Я завёл матрицу, которая хранит текущее состояние поворота катающегося шара. Когда пользователь тянет мышью, я получаю череду событий перемещения мыши, и каждый раз при перемещении вычисляю, на сколько градусов вокруг текущих `X` и `Y`, как их видит пользователь, изменился поворот. Затем вычисляю матрицу, которая представляет эти два поворота и умножаю в обратном порядке изначальную матрицу поворота сферы на нее - обратный порядок нужен по той причине, что поворот происходит с точки зрения камеры, а не с точки зрения пространства модели.

#### Проблема

Но при такой реализации, вторая сфера не будет менять точку соприкосновения с первой сферой (будет как бы скользить по ней), как можно реализовать аналитически поворот точки соприкосновения шаров в терминах матриц?

**Вот [код](https://github.com/AndrewStrizh/spheres-with-webGL), если кому интересно.**

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy , вы запускаете это на статическом http сервере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имея два соседних положения сферы можно найти плоскость в которой она катится. Тогда сфера вращается вокруг нормали к этой плоскости. Скорость вращения в два раза больше скорости движения точки касания сферы. Надеюсь вы поняли. Изменения ниже заставляют кота вращаться без проскальзывания:

> ```
> $ git diff
> diff --git a/script.js b/script.js
> index 3de3f98..27b6515 100644
> --- a/script.js
> +++ b/script.js
> @@ -207,8 +207,12 @@ let mouseDown = false;
>  let lastMouseX = null;
>  let lastMouseY = null;
>  
> +let lastT = undefined;
> +
>  let sphereRotationMatrix = mat4.create();
>  mat4.identity(sphereRotationMatrix);
> +let sphereOrientationMatrix = mat4.create();
> +mat4.identity(sphereOrientationMatrix);
>  
>  
>  function MouseDown(event) {
> @@ -462,10 +466,31 @@ function drawScene(ambientR,ambientG,ambientB) {
>      gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indexData2.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
>  
>  
> +    mat4.translate(mvMatrix,sphereRotationMatrix);
> +
> +    const t = vec3.create();
> +    t[0] = mvMatrix[12];
> +    t[1] = mvMatrix[13];
> +    t[2] = mvMatrix[14];
> +    vec3.add(t, [xPos, yPos, zPos]);
> +    vec3.add(t, [0, 0, 6]);
> +    if (lastT !== undefined) {
> +        const axis = vec3.create();
> +        vec3.cross(lastT, t, axis);
> +        const angle = vec3.length(axis);
> +        if (angle > 0) {
> +            vec3.normalize(axis, axis);
> +            const r = mat4.create();
> +            mat4.identity(r);
> +            mat4.rotate(r, 2 * angle, axis);
> +            mat4.multiply(r, sphereOrientationMatrix, sphereOrientationMatrix);
> +        }
> +    }
> +    lastT = t;
> +    mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, sphereOrientationMatrix, mvMatrix);
>  
> -    mat4.translate(mvMatrix,sphereRotationMatrix);
> -    mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, sphereRotationMatrix);
>      gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
>      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, sphereTexture);
>      gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);
> ```

**P.S.** WebGL для меня новая технология. В коде перемешаны движения сфер и их расположение в пространстве относительно камеры. Всё это делает решение хрупким. Считайте этот код прототипом или источником идей.